# Solving Integral to show PMF is legitimate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with pdf

$$f(x|\alpha, \beta) = \dfrac{x^{\alpha-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)(1+x)^{\alpha+\beta}}$$ $$x > 0$$.

where $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $B(\cdot)$ denotes the beta function defined by $B(\alpha, \beta) = \int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$

$$B(\alpha, \beta) = \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)/\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$\Gamma(\alpha+1) = \alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$$

$$\Gamma(1) = 1$$

I know that in order to show that this is a legitimate pdf I have to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$ but i'm struggling with evaluating the integral. Any help?

Comment: using Mathematica $f$ integrates to 1 over $(0,\infty)$, calculations involve the hypergeometric2f1 function

Comment: For $\,x<0 \,\,f(x|\alpha, \beta)$ is not well-defined. For $x\geqslant0$
$$\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{\alpha-1}}{(1+x)^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$$
To integrate,  make the substitution $\displaystyle t=\frac{1}{1+x}$

Answer (score 3):

You need the substitution
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{x}{1+x} \\
dy &= \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}
\end{align}

plugging this in, you will find
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx
&= \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{(1+x)^{\alpha+\beta}}\ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{(1+x)^{\alpha+\beta-2}} \ dy \\
&= ... \\
&= \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1} \ dy
\end{align}
So the integral is exactly the definition of the $B$ function, thus this is equal to 1.